# Vim: Auto Replace Tabs with Spaces on Save

Tags: vim

My vim always automatically converts tabs into spaces whenever I save (:w) a `Go` file (*.go), which is not what I want.

My vim is cloned from https://github.com/freedombird9/vim_anywhere. Besides that, I installed `vim-go` with `Vundle`.

I looked my `.vimrc` and the plugin folder for possible configs, basically configs like `autocmd` `BufWritePre` and `:write` that could change the save behavior. But I did not find anything that suggests there's a conversion before save. I also didn't see such a setting in [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go).

Comment: How do you know that it does auto replace on save ?!!! are you sure when you hit tab it inserts real tabs ?!!! your vim_anywhere `.vimrc` has `set expandtab` it means it will replaces every tab you insert by spaces. Do `set list` on a *go* file and check whether your tabs are real tab characters.

Comment: When the file is first opened/created, you can also check the `set expandtab?` and see if vim shows `expandtab` or `_no_expandatb`. This is the base vim setting to expand a tab to a number of spaces (the number as defined by the base `tabstop` variable.   [see: http://http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27expandtab%27 ]

Comment: @dNitro I tried that, they're indeed tabs (^I), but after I hit :w, those tabs are in struct definitions or initializations are converted to spaces.  Tabs in other places are not touched at all.

Comment: @JFreebird vim-go does autoformatting on save, disabling it may do the trick! give it a try: add `let g:go_fmt_autosave = 0` to your *.vimrc* file.